# Problem installing Android workload for MAUI Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4.1 according to these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation. I started a new CometApp project and I get the following error: NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-maccatalyst, net6.0-ios, net6.0-android.

I then run: dotnet workload install android

....and get the following error.

> Failed to update the advertising manifest
> microsoft.net.workload.emscripten: Failed to validate package signing.
>
> Verifying
> Microsoft.NET.Workload.Emscripten.Manifest-6.0.100.6.0.0-rtm.21505.3
>
> error: NU3004: The package is not signed.
>
> Package signature validation failed.
>
> . Failed to update the advertising manifest
> microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain: Failed to validate package
> signing.
>
> Verifying
> Microsoft.NET.Workload.Mono.ToolChain.Manifest-6.0.100.6.0.0-rtm.21508.16
>
> error: NU3004: The package is not signed.
>
> Package signature validation failed.

I have already added this source to Nuget config:

> https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-public/vside/_packaging/xamarin-impl/nuget/v3/index.json

Any suggestions to what might be the issue?

Comment: I am not sure this is a good fit for Stackoverflow. If you have a bug or an issue with documentation or installation of an unreleased version of something, its probably best to talk to the authors / github or file a bug report

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2840

Comment: Thanks, but tried the suggestions there without luck.

Comment: Have you tried using [Maui-check](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check) ?

Comment: Yes, tried all versions of maui-check I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was resolved after installing the Microsoft Visual 2022 - Preview Version 17.1.0

Comment: Likewise I had to upgrade to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.7.5 and then the workload install started working again - go figure ...

Answer (score 23):

For me it helped to:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete everything from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\metadata\workloads`
3. Run `dotnet workload install maui` in command line

Comment: Workload ID maui isn't supported on this platform.

Comment: I've just had to perform these steps in VS2022 17.7.6 after changing references from net6 to net7 in my MAUI project.  Fixed the issue straight away.

Comment: Spent countless hours on this and to no avail until I found your solution and it worked! VS2022 was to install workload wasm-tools and android but when I did, it kept telling me it was already installed and even after reboot as suggested by VS2022, it still wouldn't work!! What a pain! Wish I had found this sooner. Thanks for sharing!