# Failed to update the advertising manifest

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I was working on blazor over maui, vs2022 17.1 preview 2. Then it stopped working, running maui-check on power shell, I get some errors, I tried to fix them and then I get the following:

Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios: microsoft.net.sdk.ios.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain: microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.tvos: microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst: microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maui: microsoft.net.sdk.maui.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.macos: microsoft.net.sdk.macos.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten: microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.android: microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-6.0.200 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.).
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-6.0.200.msi.x64 (31.0.101-preview.10.59)
Workload installation failed. Rolling back installed packs...
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-6.0.200.msi.x64 (31.0.101-preview.9.16)
Installation rollback failed: One or more errors occurred. (microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-6.0.200.msi.x64::31.0.101-preview.9.16 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.))
Workload installation failed: One or more errors occurred. (microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-6.0.200.msi.x64::31.0.101-preview.10.59 is not found in NuGet feeds [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.))
Description:
Install one or more workloads.

I have tried to untick some of my NuGet sources but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions?

I have tried to update manually from powershell each package, the maui one gives the same error but the other ones update to a different version 6.0.0-rc2 and after running maui-check it doesn't recognize it

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check/issues/134

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/18628

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing Android workload for MAUI Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69522872/problem-installing-android-workload-for-maui-visual-studio-2022)

Comment: thanks, but all of the three are about a different failure, the package is not signed, mine is not found, as I did it running the maui-check the fix tool, I understand, should find the correct feed, however is not, does anyone know the correct feed?

Comment: by the way, I have the latest version of VS2022

Answer (score 4):

remove one of the nuget feeders, that fixed it

Comment: Fixed it for me

Comment: Have you removed the standard nuget.org feed or what did you do?

Comment: Fixed it for me! Just keep nuget.org and offline packages active.